Math PhD chances
I am a Math major currently in my second year. I go to a large US state school and I recently got my grades back for my intro real analysis class. It was disastrous but expected. I got a B+. I want to go to Math PhD and I am looking for suggestions to overcome this. I will be applying to the Top 20-50 Math PhD programs and would like suggestions to strengthen my profile. I know intro real analysis sequence is the most important thing but looking to see if there’s still a chance after this poor performance.
Any suggestions regarding what courses to take or how to study properly to get proper grades or how to improve other aspects of my application are welcomed.
I will be taking intro real 2 next semester along with algebra and topology.
Edit: I essentially wanted to ask will getting (A) in higher level courses after real analysis be sufficient enough for academic ability to not make a difference or does intro real analysis 1 have some inherent things one looks forward to in an applicant?

One "modest" grade isn't a disaster. Analysis, algebra, and topology are all about equally important. Maybe you need to do more exercises. Maybe you need more feedback. Maybe you need to ask more questions.

It was disastrous but expected. I got a B+. --- This is disastrous? You got "above average" in an upper level undergraduate course in your 3rd semester. That said, I think what will help a lot is to do excellent (best in the class, and then some if possible) work in at least 2 or 3 core classes (e.g. 2nd semester real analysis, abstract algebra, topology, etc.) to establish high upper limits on your potential and to secure some good recommendations. Maybe postpone upper level undergraduate courses until you're actually an upper level undergraduate. (continued)

Also, make sure you go well beyond just taking classes -- things like the Putnam Exam (and try to do reasonably well), REU's, Budapest Semesters in Mathematics, etc. As for "what courses to take or how to study properly", these are things you need to talk to some of your professors about, who are in a much better position to advise you than people who know nothing about you.

Thank you for the suggestions. Perhaps I shouldn’t have used the word disastrous. I will definitely try to improve my study habits to improve my scores in the next semesters. I definitely participate a lot in classroom and do exercises outside of the classroom but my proofs lacked considerations of edge cases or are correct but not very rigorous. As for Putnam,I will definitely keep on giving it as I love it. As for the research, I did one small project which got published in an undergrad journal but it kind of seemed trivial.

Grades are not the only deciding factor in a PhD application - and what’s more, a B+ in a difficult module is not a bad grade. As well as your academic performance, they will be looking for someone who genuinely loves maths, beyond learning content for exams, because after all PhDs are long and very difficult. Demonstrate this by describing in your application that you ask questions about maths beyond the curriculum, that you think deeply about the content, and that you are eager to research maths. Hope this helps.

@TopologyTitan: beyond learning content for exams --- Seeing this induced me to expand on my earlier comment about doing excellent in 2 or 3 core classes. I mean more than just doing very well (even perfect) on graded exams. I mean things like beyond-the-call-of-duty write-ups for turned-in homework, being clearly-on-top-of-everything in classroom participation, study of supplementary topics the instructor suggests that some might want to investigate (or better yet, topics the student independently investigates), etc. And doing so without coming across as a brown-nosing know-it-all.
